# AsyncStorage return [object object] - react native

Tags: react-native

I want to use `AsyncStorage` but it returns `[object object]`:

`Phone.js` component:

```
        commonHelper.setData("commonConstants.KEY_CODE",'code');

             this.goTo('Activation');
```

`Activation.js` component:

```
   const code = commonHelper.getData("commonConstants.KEY_CODE")
   this.setState({searchString:code.toString()})
```

`commonHelper.js`:

```
function getData(key) {
  try {
       const value = AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then(val => {
         return JSON.parse(val)
       });
       return value
     } catch (err) {
       throw err
     }
}

function setData(key,value) {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error saving data" + error);
  }
}
```

where is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncStorage` is returning a promise. your `getData` returns that promise.

to read the data, you need to use a `.then`

```
commonHelper.getData("commonConstants.KEY_CODE")
    .then(code => {
        this.setState({searchString:code}) // or code.toString().. depends on what you stored
    });`
```

Also, the  `return value` in your getData function is necessary because you are returning the promise in `.then`